# String comparison of Japanese characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8, internationalization, string-comparison

I need two compare to strings to see if they are the same value, both strings are in Japanese. This check seems to fail and I assume it's some shortcoming of JavaScript and UTF-8. Should it be expected for this to succeed? And how can I make it work? Can JavaScript convert to strings like `\x{57fc}` to perform comparison on?

```
var foo = '郵便番号',
    bar = '郵便番号';

if(foo == bar){
    console.log('they are the same');
}
```

## UPDATE

It appears this actually works just fine, the failure is a bigger issue with backbone validation. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You forgot the quotes on your strings!**

Run your current code with the browser console open, and you'll see a ReferenceError due to the missing quotes (the interpreter will think `郵便番号` is an identifier, not a string).

Wrap your strings in proper quotes, and it just works, JavaScript can handle UTF-8 just fine:

```
var foo = '郵便番号',
    bar = '郵便番号';

if(foo == bar){
    console.log('they are the same');
}
```

Regarding your second question, you can use `'\u57fc'`, but usually you don't need to; it's the same as a literal `'埼'`.

Comment: My code sample was wrong, I am wrapping these values in quotes.

Comment: And it doesn't work for you? Code above worked for me in Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

Possible try (foo === bar), two equal signs and 3 equal signs have a slightly different function and can sometimes be a problem. Not sure it will work but it should. Also is the have you got the japanese characters enclosed in quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run just fine but have to add the quotes:

```
var foo =  "\u90F5\u4FBF\u756A\u53F7",
    bar = "郵便番号";

if(foo === bar){
    console.log('they are the same');
}
```

\x is used for [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) but could not get it to work in JavaScript, the \u syntax works:

```
var foo =  /\u90F5\u4FBF\u756A\u53F7/,
    bar = "\u90F5便番号";

if(foo.test(bar)){
    console.log('they are the same');
}
```